# Navigation menu show in desktop but not show in mobile view

Tags: html, mobile, blogger

my website is [mypointgames](https://mypointgames.blogspot.com) in mobile view its navigation menu's are not  showing.
image is >[like this show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I95iN.png) and also i want to show description image instead title.

Comment: In this case you need to convert your theme to responsive design and show desktop theme on mobile devices.

Comment: please tell how

Comment: Follow the answer below

Comment: problem is menu links "home , contact us" like these buttons are not show in mobile.

Comment: You need to make your site responsive that need a good knowledge of HTML and CSS.

Comment: my site is seegamingzone.blogspot.com/?m=1 its navigation is not showing if you have any script or css then please tell.  i use this template 
Name:     Awesome Inc.
Designer: Tina Chen
URL:      tinachen.org

Comment: It is the same problem you need to show desktop theme on mobile devices as below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Theme > Edit mobile theme > Select "No. Show desktop theme on mobile devices" and press Save. Now go back to your site and check.

If you don't understand [check here](https://1minbd.blogspot.com/2016/01/mobile-friendly-blogger-design.html)